# Excel: how do I use =datedif with conditional formatting to highlight date cells in a table?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, datediff, date-difference

I'm having a bad brain day and I just can't figure this out, lol.

I have two columns in a table, F and G, that contain dates (in date format). I want to use conditional formatting such that when I open the workbook, Excel compares the dates in both columns to today's date (`TODAY()`? `NOW()`?) and if the date is in the past, format the cell red, if it's within 90 days, format the cell yellow, and if the date is over 90 days in the future, format the cell green. Can you help, or at least pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks so much.

I tried `="datedif($F$3, today()) < 90" and =DATEDIF($F$3, TODAY(),"m")`<3 where F3 is the first column/row that contains a date, and applied it to the range `$F$3:$G$118` (last column/row with a date. It didn't do anything, lol.

Comment: Why `DATEDIF()` and why not this way: **`For Past Dates`** --> `=$F3<TODAY()` | **`Within 90 Days`** --> `=($F3>=TODAY())*($F3<=TODAY()+90)` | **`For Future over 90 Days`** --> `=$F3>TODAY()+90`

Comment: I think it's just an issue with using absolute vs. relative cell references. If you use `=(TODAY()-F3)>0` for past dates, for example, it should work.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya because I really like making things more difficult for myself? :) That worked; thank you!

Comment: Also according to docs If the start_date is greater than the end_date, the result will be #NUM!  so =DATEDIF($F$3, TODAY(),"m")<3 where $F$3 is in the future wouldn't work